# Sink (Headset) Application in CSR BlueCore5, ADK 2.5

Tags: bluetooth, csr, headset, reconnect, sink

Does anyone have experience with CSR's BlueCore5-Multimedia and the ADK 2.5 Sink Application. I am working on CSR's CNS09010v3 development board and am using their Audio Development Kit (ADK 2.5). I do not modify anything on their example Sink application. There are two configurations for BC5MM - DEBUG and RELEASE.

1. Open the Sink workspace from their xIDE3 development program.
2. Compile and run the Sink application in DEBUG Configuration (the dev boards is already configured with the included in the ADK - Sink Configuration Tool).
3. Pair the headset with an iPhone 5S.
4. I am able to play music and make a phone call.
5. I stop the application and run it again. The headset connects automatically to the iPhone 5S and again am able to play music and make a phone call.

The problem is when I run the Sink application in RELEASE configuration and unplug the SPI Programming and Debugging interface cable. The headset does not want to connect automatically to the already paired iPhone 5S. If the application is running in RELEASE configuration and the cable is plugged it connects automatically. The difference between the two configurations is that in DEBUG the application sends debug messages through the SPI port and the xIDE3 displays them. I hope that this description is enough for someone to help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @todorkr- Sorry, I don't know the answer but want to know ,Do you have any idea how  to configure the PSKEYs. Actually I am using the CSR8670 kit and trying to make use of device specific AT-COMMANDS but not able to make it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are experiencing is caused by a call to printf() or some other function, which sends output to std.out. 
CSR has documented this in CS-236868-UGP1ADKSinkUserGuide.pdf:

> 3.3. Enabling Debug Output
>
> Adding the DEBUG_PRINT_ENABLED Define Symbol enables debug output.
>   This can be set in the sink_debug.h file. Debug for certain files
>   can be enabled and disabled by editing the relevant #define(s) in
>   sink_debug.h.
>
> **Note:**
>   When debug is enabled in the application or libraries the
>   application does not run without a debugger attached.

So please make sure that you don't call even indirectly (e.g. via macro) any std. output function.